# How To GET Full List Streets Uruguay

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

for a project of geographical location, it would be specifying get the full list of streets in the country Uruguay organized by Town.For example Montevideo
The list of streets want to know if there is any database Open Street Maps that can provide me the information.
Also if there OpenStreetMaps way to configure a server and to make consultations by a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download a full [OSM extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) of Uruguay. However to generate a street list by town you will additionally need a geocoder such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Also take a look at this [answer at help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/23488/export-streets-names/23493) to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply is helping me a lot because I could locate more help in the forums openstreetmap

Answer (score 0):

Response forum OpenStreetMaps
So I used this solution:

```
Download the .pbf for your country http://download.geofabrik.de
Download the polygon file for the desired municipality from https://github.com/JamesChevalier/cities
Do this: osmosis --read-pbf-fast spain-latest.osm.pbf file="spain-latest.osm.pbf" --bounding-polygon file="cadiz.poly" --write-xml file="cadiz.osm"
```

Now you have a .osm file for the municipality. Inside it is all the information (streets, buildings, monuments, etc) for that city.

You can use osmfilter or grep to extract the info your want.

websites that were me help

https://github.com/JamesChevalier/cities

http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

http://extract.bbbike.org/

Regards